# Merging onsubmit scripts

Tags: javascript

I have a form which has two scripts that run on submit; one to disable the submit button after being clicked once, the other to add the uk country code to the phoneNumber field. I can only get one of them to run at a time, how can i get them to both run?

```html
  <form action="https://123.com" method="post" onsubmit="return checkForm(this);"> 
   <input name="PhoneNumber" type="tel" required="">
   <input name="myButton" type="submit" value="Submit">
   </form>
```

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function checkForm(form)
  {
    //
    // validate form fields
    //

    form.myButton.disabled = true;
    return true;
  }
</script> 
  <script>
function checkForm(f) {
  const phoneNumberField = f.querySelector("[name='PhoneNumber']");
  if(phoneNumberField.value.startsWith("0")){
    phoneNumberField.value = "44" + phoneNumberField.value.substring(1);
  }
   return true; // Just for demo to stop the form submitting
}
  </script>
```

Comment: Why dont you put everything into one method, for example `handleFormSubmit()` and from inside that method you can call all your methods you need

Comment: Sorry, pretty new to all this. Just put everything within the brackets minus the script tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `onclick` attribute. Use `Element.addEventListener()` instead

```js
document.getElementById('my-form').addEventListener('submit', checkForm)

function checkForm1(form) {
  form.myButton.disabled = true;
}
function checkForm2(f) {
  const phoneNumberField = f.querySelector("[name='PhoneNumber']");
  if (phoneNumberField.value.startsWith("0")) {
    phoneNumberField.value = "44" + phoneNumberField.value.substring(1);
  }
}
function checkForm(e) {
  checkForm1(e.target)
  checkForm2(e.target)
  // This stops the form from submitting
  e.preventDefault()
  e.stopPropagation()
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form id="my-form" action="https://123.com" method="post">
  <input name="PhoneNumber" type="tel" required="">
  <input name="myButton" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

OR

```js
document.getElementById('my-form').addEventListener('submit', checkForm1)
document.getElementById('my-form').addEventListener('submit', checkForm2)
document.getElementById('my-form').addEventListener('submit', cancel)

function checkForm1(e) {
  e.target.myButton.disabled = true;
}

function checkForm2(e) {
  const phoneNumberField = e.target.querySelector("[name='PhoneNumber']");
  if (phoneNumberField.value.startsWith("0")) {
    phoneNumberField.value = "44" + phoneNumberField.value.substring(1);
  }
}

function cancel(e) {
  // This stops the form from submitting
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form id="my-form" action="https://123.com" method="post">
  <input name="PhoneNumber" type="tel" required="">
  <input name="myButton" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, however, both options you've given stop the form from submitting. The phone number changes with both options @yunzen

Comment: That is for demonstration only. I will mark in the code, what stops the submitting

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot